# Real sequence s.t. $\lim_{n} (a_n+a_{n+1}) = r$ and $\lim_{n} (a_n+a_{n+2}) = s$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose that 
>   $$
> \lim_{n} (a_n+a_{n+1}) = r, \qquad \lim_{n} (a_n+a_{n+2}) = s
> $$
>   where $r,s$ are finite real numbers. Then $r=s$ and 
>   $$
> \lim_{n} a_n = \frac{r}{2}.
> $$

I found this problem in a booklet and I have tried to solve it simply using definitions, getting stuck. I apologize, I was in a hurry and I didn't have the time to write my attempts. By the way: for $n$ large enough we have 
$$
\vert a_n+a_{n+1}-r \vert < \varepsilon, \qquad \vert a_n+a_{n+2}-s \vert < \varepsilon
$$
Therefore 
$$
\vert a_{n+1} - a_{n+2} - (r-s) \vert =\vert a_n+a_{n+1}-r - (a_n+a_{n+2}-s) \vert < 2\varepsilon
$$
But then I did not have the idea of Sami Ben Rodhame (I thank him for his kind answer): just call $u_{n+1}:= a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}$.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: After 20+ months and 80+ questions asked oin the site, one could hope not having to explain this.

Comment: I have already edited my question and I have apologized for my bad behaviour. What else can I do? I apologize again, but I really do not know what else I can do to improve my question in order to save it from closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$u_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$$
then by hypothesis we have (we subtruct the two limits)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n+1}=s-r$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-a_{n}=s-r$$
hence we find
$$2\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-(a_{n+1}-a_{n})+(a_n+a_{n+1}))=r-s+r=2r-s$$
Can you complete the answer?